# Trouble with reading .WAV file in C

Tags: c, matlab, audio

I am trying to read a 5-second .wav file full of "silence" to test the code in C. I was able to read the header however when trying to extract the date field where the content shoul be (which I believe should be zero) it generates some numbers. According to the images below.

**Here is my C code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char buff[10000];
int main(){

    int i;
    FILE * fp;
    FILE *flog;

    if ((fp = fopen("Silencio2.wav", "rb")) == NULL){
        printf("Fail!");
        exit(1);
    }


    fseek(fp, 44, 0); // read from 44 byte to the end.
    fread(buff,sizeof(int),1024,fp);
    flog = fopen("Silencio2.txt","w"); // make a log file to generate chart

    // print in hex to console and decimal to log file.
    for(i = 0; i < 5000 ; i++){
     printf("%i == %hhx \n",i,buff[i]);
     fprintf(flog,"%d\n",buff[i]);
     buff[i] = 0;
    }
    fclose(flog);
    return 0;
}
```

**.Wav Header Reading Image:**

[image: .Wav Header Reading Image]

As we can see the program correctly reads the header by bringing the coherent information, RIFF, WAVE, FMT, 1 channel, 16bit, 16khz and the beginning of the date (40 ~ 44).

**Source that I'm using to read the .wav file:** http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

**Characteristics of the .wav file:**

Bitrate: 16 bit PCM;
Channels: 1;
SampleRate: 16khz.
Time: 5s;
Generated by Audacity with the function of generating silence.

After saving this log in txt I am pasting in matlab and reading the original file on it, in order to print the comparative chart between the 2 to validate my data, however I am getting the following output:

**1st Graph Processing of matlab with the function readaudio();**

**2nd Graph log generated by my code.**

[image: Chart from matlab with comparative betwen 2 files, mycode and matlab]

**Script Matlab:**

```
[Sile2,Fs] = audioread('Silencio2.wav');
title('Gerado pelo MATLAB');
subplot(2, 1, 2);
plot(CodeSile2);
title('Meu código');
subplot(2, 1, 1);
plot(Sile2);
```

**The question that remains is:** Are my results consistent? For besides the divergence of magnitude of the signal there is also a noise, that I do not know how to explain the reason of it. Since the signal was generated through a generator of silence.

PS: Yes I know the libsnd but how I want to make a embed system with this code in a stm32 / esp32, the less libraries use, better.

Comment: If the data is 16-bit why are you printing it 8 bits at a time?

Comment: Sorry i don't get your question :( in for loop i'm printing in integer/ decimals, in C a integer is equals 2 bytes = 16 bits

Comment: You said your data is 16-bit PCM which means each sample is 16-bits in size. You are reading the data into `char buff[10000];` and printing it with `buff[i]` which is a char or 8 bits. You need to interpret the sample data differently.

Comment: It's true i'll fix it, thank you!

Comment: OT: when calling C library functions, always check the returned value for any error indication.  When an error indication is found, then output to `stderr`, both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` does that functionality very well

Comment: regarding: `fread(buff,sizeof(int),1024,fp);`  this reads a total (on a 16 bit architecture) of 2048 bytes.  However. this: `for(i = 0; i < 5000 ; i++){` is trying to process 5000 bytes. so everything from byte 2049 through 5000 is trash, not valid sound data

Comment: this: `16khz` indicates 16k samples per second, so reading just the first 1024 samples is only 1/16th of a second of the available sound data

Comment: regarding: `fseek(fp, 44, 0);`  This is making the assumption that the defined value of `SEEK_SET` is 0.  This assumption is not backed up by the MAN page for `fseek()`

Comment: the end of the posted code is missing the statement: `fclose( fp );`

Comment: the code should be reading the sub chunk 2 'size' field to determine the number of samples in the sub chunk.  Note, each sample is the size found in offset 34+35 and note the byte order of that field, so need to read it one byte at a time and assemble the resulting value then divide by 8 to get the number of bytes in each sample.  In other words, the code needs to pay attention to the values in the fields in the head(s) and that includes the format of that field being big endian or little endian